# Track cursor movement of all the visitors on a web site

Tags: javascript, php, user-interface, jquery-ui, dom-events

I know that there are many analytics tools available to track cursor movement of all the visitors on a website - these tools basically track the movement by giving a Javascript code which need to be pasted on the website. They all are quite expensive

I am trying to develop it for my own website - a tracking code installed on my website and the cursor movements viewed on some other page/website.

I have seen in Google docs wherein if many people open the doc. different cursor are visible in different colors each corresponding to a particular visitor. I want to develop similar functionality for website.

I have tried to Google but I am not able to find a starting point from where I can start developing it.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should look for is attaching a **mousemove** event listener to the root element of your webpage (body?) and make sure to specify the **capture** phase by setting the `useCapture` parameter to `true` in your call to [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). Check the [DOM event model](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture) for more details, the diagaramme is pretty self-explanatory.

a quick and dirty exemple should look like this :

```
var coords=[];
var callback = function(e) {
    // save your mouse coordinates somewhere
    coords.push({x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY});
}
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',callback,true);
```

Of course you'll need to figure out how to push these coordinates at some point to your server (and perhaps just save a sample of the coordinates).

Hope this helps.

Comment: "make sure to specify the capture phase" why?

Comment: It's simply to get the mouse event before any other listener in the chain, even if at some point an other listener prevents propagation.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.clicktale.com/  They have a free option for blogs and small sites.

Deciphering your analytics is going to be the hard part.

If you want to do this with jquery, use $(document).mousemove(...).  As long as another tag hasn't prevented propagation, you'll be able to do map the entire page.

**Caveat:**

I've not tested $(document).mousemove(...), it may be $("body").mousemove(...) or $("html").mousemove(...)